# Get logged in user details from identity in service

Tags: asp.net, service, asp.net-identity, .net-core

I can get details of logged in user from controller injecting IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor. But when I try it in my service, it does not work. I get these error

```
{System.Exception: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you a...
```

What I have done is create an **IUserService** interface. Then added GetUser method there with its implementation as:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor context, UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    public async Task<User> GetUser()
    {
        return await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(_context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    }
}
```

I have added  `services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();` in my IServiceCollection too.

Comment: It seems that you are calling GetUser method after response has been sent back in which per request services have been disposed already. Where do you access GetUser method?

Comment: I have NeaService class where I inject IUserService and get the details of the logged in user who has recorded the data and save it into my DB.

Comment: And is the `NeaService` class singleton too?

Comment: yeah they are also singleton!

Answer (score 0):

Don't add `UserService` as a singleton. It has an injected `UserManager` that itself has an injected `DbContext` that will explode if you try to use it like this and it is almost certainly getting disposed so on second use it won't work. Instead you are safest adding it as a transient object:

```
services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
```

To add to this, you must consider your hierarchy of objects. If a singleton object has a transient one injected into it, that transient object will remain with the singleton for the lifetime and will likely be disposed by the DI framework, leaving your singleton in an unsafe state.

Comment: I have tried making Transient and Scoped too but it just went worse!

Comment: How could it be worse?

Comment: I am surprised myself!! Are there any other ways!!

Comment: No, you cannot have a singleton service which takes an `IHttpContextAccessor` or anything to do with a `DbContext`. Use transient as it is a lightweight, stateless object. If you have other errors, post them and we can try to fix them.

Comment: I get error that you cannot call new thread when one thread is already running while trying to save the details of the logged in user in my db.

Comment: OK, so we have probably solved the question you asked above, but now you have another problem. How have you added the context, is that also a singleton or some other method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139383/discussion-between-user3127109-and-davidg).